# png returned from database in MVC3 not displaying in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8, png

In my MVC site, I'm returning image from a database, using the controller action below. This works fine for the most part. The only problem I'm having is that in IE8 and lower, pngs aren't being displayed. They show the red "X" instead. Any ideas?

```
public ActionResult Image(Guid id)
{
    ContentService svc = new ContentService();

    BinaryContent content = svc.GetBinaryContentById(id, "en-US");

    string mimeType = string.Format("image/{0}", content.BinaryType);
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", id.ToString(), content.BinaryType);

    return File(content.Data, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Try setting the mimeType to `"image/png"`.

Comment: are you certain that the content.BinaryType method is returning "png" (lowercase, not periods, etc..)? the filename may have to be the same as the url (or you might have to use the version without the filename), though i'm not certain.

Comment: I have confirmed that the BinaryType property is returning "png" so the mimeType is being set to "image/png". Also, I wasn't originally setting the file name, and I had the same problem. I'd actually added the file name in an attempt to fix it!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/ba85dc5c-04b8-4bc1-a893-1c465bedf4be - this is a crappy work around, but at least a starting point perhaps

Comment: The problem was not with the browser itself. We tried applying the registry fix for pngs, but it had not effect, and pngs from other sites were displaying okay anyway. In the end, I just worked around the problem by converting pngs to jpegs only when the user was on IE 8 or earlier. It's a bit of a kludge, but it gets the job done. Thank you all for your help!